# One of two PersistentVolumeClaims' status is "Pending"

Tags: kubernetes, kubernetes-pvc

I have a file has PV, Service and 2 Pod statefulset including Dynamic PVC.
When I deployed the file, a problem happened at PVC status.

```
# kubectl get pvc
NAME            STATUS    VOLUME           CAPACITY   ACCESS MODES   STORAGECLASS       AGE
www-web-0       Bound     pv-test          10Gi       RWO            my-storage-class   7m19s
www-web-1       Pending                                              my-storage-class   7m17s
```

One of PVC's Status is "Pending" and the reason is "Storage class name not found".
But one of PVC was created normally.

Below is the content of the file.

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: PersistentVolume
metadata:
  name: pv-test
  labels:
    type: local
spec:
  accessModes:
  - ReadWriteOnce
  persistentVolumeReclaimPolicy: Delete
  storageClassName: "my-storage-class"
  capacity:
    storage: 10Gi
  hostPath:
    path: /tmp/data
    type: DirectoryOrCreate
---
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: nginx
  labels:
    app: nginx
spec:
  ports:
  - port: 80
    name: web
  clusterIP: None
  selector:
    app: nginx
---
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: StatefulSet
metadata:
  name: web
spec:
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: nginx # has to match .spec.template.metadata.labels
  serviceName: "nginx"
  replicas: 2 # by default is 1
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: nginx # has to match .spec.selector.matchLabels
    spec:
      terminationGracePeriodSeconds: 10
      containers:
      - name: nginx
        image: k8s.gcr.io/nginx-slim:0.8
        ports:
        - containerPort: 80
          name: web
        volumeMounts:
        - name: www
          mountPath: /usr/share/nginx/html
  volumeClaimTemplates:
  - metadata:
      name: www
    spec:
      accessModes: [ "ReadWriteOnce" ]
      storageClassName: "my-storage-class"
      resources:
        requests:
          storage: 1Gi
```

If someone knows the cause, let me know.
Thanks in advance.

Describe information about PV, PVC (www-web-1), Pod (web-1)

```
kubectl describe pv pv-test
Name:            pv-test
Labels:          type=local
Annotations:     kubectl.kubernetes.io/last-applied-configuration:
                   {"apiVersion":"v1","kind":"PersistentVolume","metadata":{"annotations":{},"labels":{"type":"local"},"name":"pv-test"},"spec":{"accessModes...
                 pv.kubernetes.io/bound-by-controller: yes
Finalizers:      [kubernetes.io/pv-protection]
StorageClass:    my-storage-class
Status:          Bound
Claim:           default/www-web-0
Reclaim Policy:  Delete
Access Modes:    RWX
VolumeMode:      Filesystem
Capacity:        10Gi
Node Affinity:   <none>
Message:
Source:
    Type:          HostPath (bare host directory volume)
    Path:          /tmp/data
    HostPathType:  DirectoryOrCreate
Events:            <none>

#kubectl  describe pvc www-web-1
Name:          www-web-1
Namespace:     default
StorageClass:  my-storage-class
Status:        Pending
Volume:
Labels:        app=nginx
Annotations:   <none>
Finalizers:    [kubernetes.io/pvc-protection]
Capacity:
Access Modes:
VolumeMode:    Filesystem
Events:
  Type       Reason              Age               From                         Message
  ----       ------              ----              ----                         -------
  Warning    ProvisioningFailed  20s (x7 over 2m)  persistentvolume-controller  storageclass.storage.k8s.io "my-storage-class" not found
Mounted By:  web-1


#kubectl describe po web-1
Name:               web-1
Namespace:          default
Priority:           0
PriorityClassName:  <none>
Node:               <none>
Labels:             app=nginx
                    controller-revision-hash=web-6596ffb49b
                    statefulset.kubernetes.io/pod-name=web-1
Annotations:        <none>
Status:             Pending
IP:
Controlled By:      StatefulSet/web
Containers:
  nginx:
    Image:        k8s.gcr.io/nginx-slim:0.8
    Port:         80/TCP
    Host Port:    0/TCP
    Environment:  <none>
    Mounts:
      /usr/share/nginx/html from www (rw)
      /var/run/secrets/kubernetes.io/serviceaccount from default-token-lnfvq (ro)
Conditions:
  Type           Status
  PodScheduled   False
Volumes:
  www:
    Type:       PersistentVolumeClaim (a reference to a PersistentVolumeClaim in the same namespace)
    ClaimName:  www-web-1
    ReadOnly:   false
  default-token-lnfvq:
    Type:        Secret (a volume populated by a Secret)
    SecretName:  default-token-lnfvq
    Optional:    false
QoS Class:       BestEffort
Node-Selectors:  <none>
Tolerations:     node.kubernetes.io/not-ready:NoExecute for 300s
                 node.kubernetes.io/unreachable:NoExecute for 300s
Events:
  Type     Reason            Age                      From               Message
  ----     ------            ----                     ----               -------
  Warning  FailedScheduling  3m43s (x183 over 8m46s)  default-scheduler  pod has unbound immediate PersistentVolumeClaims (repeated 3 times)
```

Comment: Please, run `kubectl describe pvc www-web-1`, and update your answer with any returned "events" information. This will may help to find the cause.

Comment: I commented it in the above issue. The returned event is "Storage class name not found". But what i want to know is why the first pvc succeed to create.

Answer (score 1):

Your volume `pv-test` has `accessModes: - ReadWriteOnce` I think you need to create one more volume for second pod.

So I think if `www-web-1`  is also trying to mount `pv-test` it won't be able to mount it.

Comment: I also tested with Option "ReadWriteMany" but the result was same.

Comment: Can you run `describe` on pod, pv and pvc and share the output.

Comment: I added each described information about pv, pvc and pod.

Comment: how are you creating `my-storage-class` ?

Answer (score 0):

You are using hostpath volume to store the data. You are using /tmp/data on the host. Ensure that /tmp/data directory exists in all the nodes in the cluster.

Comment: hostPath type is DirectoryOrCreate. If the directory doesn't exist, it will create.

Comment: Remove storage class from pv definition

Comment: For hostpath you don't need storage class. Remove it from pv and pvc definitions

Comment: You definitely need one pv each for stateful pod